# Usage of the word "typical"

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, adjectives, pejorative-language

Some friends and I have been debating for a while now the significance of the word "typical", more specifically the pejorative connotation that, they insist, is inherent to this word. To them, for example, "this is very typical of Bob" automatically implies a reprehensible or unpleasant behaviour on Bob's end, whereas I've always used it to express a recognizable characteristic or pattern in Bob's behaviour.

I would like to settle this once and for all.  Please share your thoughts on this matter.

Comment: One can say "Bob typically buys all the beer!", and that doesn't sound negative at all!

Comment: "Well, that's typical" (and a few variations) is an idiom which carries the negative connotation, especially when used to refer to someone's behavior.  Saying that a particular apple is typical of the species is in no way negative.

Comment: @Othya - Unless followed by "... for the underage girls at the parties."

Comment: Do not expect people who use the collocation "implicitly inherent" to have a finely tuned sense of the English language.

Comment: The negativity that _may_ be associated with 'typical' is one of weak connotation, not denotation (that is, the dictionary definition does not involve negativity, but is often used in negative situations.

Answer (score 2):

You're correct about the denotation of the phrase, but in practice the phrase "typical of Bob" or simply "typical" is frequently used in exasperation and has picked up the negative connotation that your friends recognize. While it's not wrong to use it to reference a good behavior of an individual, it's seldom used that way in conversation.

Comment: Do you have any evidence for this?  It's true that if you're talking about someone who mostly exhibits bad behavior, then his "typical" behavior is bad, but that's practically tautological.  There's no such denotation for other uses, e.g., a typical presentation of a disease, where the word just means usual.

Comment: I've never heard the phrase "This is very typical of Bob." used in a positive light. Other uses of the word are neutral, possibly slightly clinical.

Comment: A couple of minutes in the google:  "It's **typical of Bob** Dole. It very carefully covers all the bases ...." Sen. Robert Bennett about a proposal Dole made about censuring Clinton. "It's **typical of Bob** Shaw to present an individual against an evil establishment." from a review by Peter Burnett of Shaw's novel *Night Walk*.  "It's **typical of Bob** that after he earned his degree he generously shared his experiences as a new professor..." from an 8/1/05 obit of a Robert Reich, Temple U prof.  I'm not saying you're wrong; I'm saying the plural of anecdote isn't data.

Comment: That doesn't change the fact that, in my experience, the phrase is only used negatively in conversation.

Comment: My comment has nothing to do with changing your experience, as though that were even possible.  It merely means that your experience isn't dispositive.

Comment: You don't believe that as a native English speaker I can assert that a phrase has a connotation in common parlance citing my own experience as evidence? I'm not sure how else connotation could be determined except for by the experience of native speakers. I would argue that my comments are extremely relevant to the question being asked. You're free to offer your own experience with the phrase "typical", but don't dismiss me out of hand.

Comment: Please don't tell what I believe.  Please don't tell me that I'm restricting what you can and cannot assert.  Connotation is indeed determined by native speakers.  You are not native speakers.  You are *one* native speaker, and your comments are certainly relevant to your own experience.  I am free to offer my own experience, but of course, I didn't do that.  Instead I offered evidence of general usage that contradicts your claim of negative use only.  This isn't to dismiss you "out of hand."; it's to provide evidence to counter your assertion.  I don't know how to make this any clearer.